# Every fifth string do pause in batch

Tags: file, batch-file

My problem is i made a thing that displays all files in directory but as it is too long and too many lines, i decided let's say for example just every fifth line it will pause.

The smaller version of code is:

`for /r %%a in (*) do echo %%a`

So I guess you have a idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Noodles said with `MORE` or :

EDIT :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a $C=1
for /r %%a in (*) do (
  IF !$C!==5 (
     echo.
     pause >nul
     set /a $C=1)
  echo %%a
  set /a $C+=1)
```

Comment: Hm, is there a way to make it skip a line after every search etc..But thank you soo much it worked

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the more command designed for this. It does a screen rather than 5 (unless you use `p 5` command).

```
C:\Users\User>more /?
Displays output one screen at a time.

MORE [/E [/C] [/P] [/S] [/Tn] [+n]] < [drive:][path]filename
command-name | MORE [/E [/C] [/P] [/S] [/Tn] [+n]]
MORE /E [/C] [/P] [/S] [/Tn] [+n] [files]
[drive:][path]filename  Specifies a file to display one
                        screen at a time.

command-name            Specifies a command whose output
                        will be displayed.

/E      Enable extended features
/C      Clear screen before displaying page
/P      Expand FormFeed characters
/S      Squeeze multiple blank lines into a single line
/Tn     Expand tabs to n spaces (default 8)

        Switches can be present in the MORE environment
        variable.

+n      Start displaying the first file at line n

files   List of files to be displayed. Files in the list
        are separated by blanks.

If extended features are enabled, the following commands
are accepted at the -- More -- prompt:

P n     Display next n lines
S n     Skip next n lines
F       Display next file
Q       Quit
=       Show line number
?       Show help line
<space> Display next page
<ret>   Display next line
```

Do do it in a for loop use `set /a` and !var! type variables (read all of set's help). See help in `For /?` and `setlocal /?`.

Comment: Maybe there is a simpler way to go? Like i mean because the scroll bar is actually shown in cmd but as i use a mode/resized window it hides the scrollbar for some weird reason. So is there a command to force the thing to show??

Comment: In the command properies (right click title bar) set the screen size and buffer size. Buffer size has to be larger than screen size to have scroll bars.